# Default Transaction Timeout

Tags: .net, configuration, transactions, timeout

I used to set Transaction timeouts by using **TransactionOptions.Timeout**, but have decided for ease of maintenance to use the config approach:

```
 <system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="00:01:00" />
  </system.transactions>
```

Of course, after putting this in, I wanted to test it was working, so reduced the timeout to 5 seconds, then ran a test that lasted longer than this - but the transaction does not appear to abort! If I adjust the test to set TransactionOptions.Timeout to 5 seconds, the test works as expected

After Investigating I think the problem appears to relate to TransactionOptions.Timeout, even though I'm no longer using it.

I still need to use TransactionOptions so I can set IsolationLevel, but I no longer set the Timeout value, if I look at this object after I create it, the timeout value is 00:00:00, which equates to infinity. Does this mean my value set in the config file is being ignored?

To summarise:

- Is it impossible to mix the config
  setting, and use of
  TransactionOptions
- If not, is there
  any way to extract the config setting
  at runtime, and use this to set the
  Timeout property
- **[Edit] OR** Set the default isolation-level without using TransactionOptions

Comment: In what config file did you set this? In which configuration section?

Comment: In app.confing directly under the <configuration> root. Also in web.config's, but the above testing was for app.config.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can mix system.transaction configuration settings and the use of the `TransactionOption` class, but there are some things you need to be aware of.

> If you use the `TransactionOption` and
>   specify a `Timeout` value, that value
>   will be used   over the
>   system.transactions/defaultTimeout
>   value.

The above is the crux of the problem in your case I think.  You are using the `TransactionOption` to specify the *isolation* level, and as a side effect you are getting an *infinite* Timeout value because infinite is the default Timeout value for `TransactionOption` if its not specified.  Though, I'm not quite sure why that is...it would make sense to default to the default Transaction Timeout.

You can implement your own TransactionOptions helper class that includes defaults that are read from app.config (if found) or default to reasonable values for a TransactionOption class that can be used.

In any case, you can still limit this by using the **system.transaction/machineSettings/maxTimeout** value.  This is an administrative setting and can only be configured through the machine.config.  You'll get a ConfigurationException if you try it from app/web.config.

```
<system.transactions>
    <machineSettings maxTimeout="00:00:30" />
</system.transactions>
```

With the **maxTimeout** set, no matter what timeout value you specify, the maximum value will be limited to the maxTimeout value.  The default maxTimeout is 00:10:00, or 10 minutes, so you wouldn't actually ever have an infinite timeout on a transaction.

You can also set the transaction IsolationLevel **explicitly** on the database connection you are using within the transaction.  Something like this?

```
   var connectionString = "Server=.;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var sqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);

                    // do database work
                    //
                    sqlTransaction.Commit();


                }

                // do other work..
                //

                scope.Complete();

            }
```

In your testing, you may need to make sure you rebuild so that the app.config is regenerated .  In my testing, it appeared that I needed to terminate the *.vshost.exe process in order for it to pick up the system.transaction configuration setting change - though I feel that may have been a fluke.  Just fyi..

Answer (score 53):

You can get the (validated) default timeout from the configuration using [`TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionmanager.defaulttimeout.aspx).

[`TransactionOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionoptions.aspx) is a struct that encapsulates timeout and isolation level. When initializing a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28VS.71%29.aspx) using the default constructor, it will always initialize the struct members to their default values:

```
TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.Timeout == default(TimeSpan); // TimeSpan.Zero
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel == default(IsolationLevel); // IsolationLevel.Serializable
```

If you want to specify an `IsolationLevel` and use the default timeout:

```
new TransactionOptions()
{
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable, // Use whatever level you require
    Timeout = TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout
};
```

Comment: This was the answer I was always hoping for! Unfortunately it is too late for me to award the answer to you, but TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout is definitely what I wanted. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I also noticed that Microsoft also uses this technique in their [documentation on System.Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx). Thanks for the useful information!

Comment: FWIW Groveling in ILSpy shows a default of 1 minute in .NET 4.0, remember this is an implementation detail, so is subject to change, use the above to double check this value!:

// System.Transactions.Configuration.DefaultSettingsSection
[ConfigurationProperty("timeout", DefaultValue = "00:01:00"), TimeSpanValidator(MinValueString = "00:00:00", MaxValueString = "10675199.02:48:05.4775807")]

Comment: @aolszowka The value of `TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout` **is** the value as specified in the configuration file. The default value is indeed 1 minute and can be modified by editing [DefaultSettingsSection.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.defaultsettingssection.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so double checking is not needed!

Comment: machineSettings or `TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout` ?

Answer (score 13):

Per Reflector, the basic rules for setting a transaction time out with the constructors of `TransactionScope` are as follows:

The **DefaultTimeOut** is determined by the first rule from below that is satisfied:

- if the constructor has a `TimeSpan` parameter, the DefaultTimeout is the that parameter
- if the constructor has a `TransactionOption` parameter, the DefaultTimeout is `transactionOption.TimeOut`
- if the constructor has a `TransactionScopeOption` parameter, the DefaultTimeout is `scopeOption.TimeOut`
- if the constructor does not have timeout parameter, the DefaultTimeout is the value specified in the app or web config file.
- otherwise, DefaultTimeOut is 1 minute.

The **MaxTimeOut** is 10 minutes unless another value is specified in the  machine.config.

The **effective timeout** for the transaction is smaller of the MaxTimeOut and DefaultTimeOut that is greater than zero. If both MaxTimeOut and DefaultTimeOut are zero, the effective timeout is the number of ticks represented by `long.MaxValue` (the infinity).

If the `TransactionScope` instance does not create a new transaction either because a transaction is passed into its constructor, or because the transaction scope option does not require it (e.g., when an ambient transaction is present and the TransactionScopeOption is Required), but a `timeOut` parameter is still passed in the constructor, a timer is started. When the timeout period elapses, the underlying transaction's `TimeOut()` method is called. The DefaultTimeOut and MaxTimeOut properties are not used in this case.

If the `transactionScopeOption == TransactionScopeOption.Supress`, the timeout is ignored and has no effect.

It is also possible to define the MaxTimeOut in the app/web config file, if the relevant section in the machine.config is overridden (note the values of the allowDefintion and allowExeDefinition attributes):

```
<sectionGroup name="system.transactions" type="System.Transactions.Configuration.TransactionsSectionGroup, System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null">
    <section name="defaultSettings" type="System.Transactions.Configuration.DefaultSettingsSection, System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    <section name="machineSettings" type="System.Transactions.Configuration.MachineSettingsSection, System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

For quick reference, here are the TransactionScope constructors:

```
public TransactionScope(Transaction transactionToUse, TimeSpan scopeTimeout, EnterpriseServicesInteropOption interopOption);
public TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption, TransactionOptions transactionOptions, EnterpriseServicesInteropOption interopOption);
public TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption, TransactionOptions transactionOptions);
public TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption, TimeSpan scopeTimeout);
public TransactionScope(Transaction transactionToUse, TimeSpan scopeTimeout);
public TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption);
```

Answer (score 9):

The config file setting is ignored when TransactionOptions are used. Creating a TransactionScope will, in most cases, create an instance of CommittableTransaction. The no arg constructor of CommittableTransaction will use the config file setting as its default timeout. TransactionScope constructors that take a TransactionOptions or TimeSpan will call one of the overloads of the CommittableTransaction class and not the no arg version. So if you want to use that value you have to grab it from the config file yourself.

When I ran into this I put the following code in a little TransactionOptionsFactory class.

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationSectionGroup sectionGroup = configuration.GetSectionGroup("system.transactions");
DefaultSettingsSection defaultSettings = (DefaultSettingsSection) sectionGroup.Sections["defaultSettings"];
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.Timeout = defaultSettings.Timeout;
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
```

Comment: Apologies Mike, I would have awarded you the bounty, but I was apparently an hour behind the bounty deadline. This solution would resolve my problem very neatly. Shame the API isn't clearer on this.

Comment: No worries MattH. I'm just glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

```
void Main()
{
    var maximumTimeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;//This step is necessary to init _maximumTimeout value, 

    FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(TransactionManager).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Single(item => item.Name == "_maximumTimeout");
    var customMaximumTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    fieldInfo.SetValue(null, customMaximumTimeout);
    maximumTimeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;

    Console.WriteLine(maximumTimeout);//01:00:00
    // use TransactionScope
}
```

Comment: As Franz concisely points out - you can do this with reflection. I found another method in the comments of this MSDN article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ajit/archive/2008/06/18/override-the-system-transactions-default-timeout-of-10-minutes-in-the-code.aspx#10417962 - unfortunately the DevOps situation at my company isn't quite what I need it to be so I don't have an easy way to update the machine.config on all the processing nodes and have the settings applied to future ones. Using reflection is a nice workaround for me.

Answer (score 1):

To put my current thoughts down:

- It is impossible to mix the config setting, and use of TransactionOptions
- The only way to extract the config setting at runtime is to read the app.config as an XML file
- The default isolation-level can only be done via transaction options, or at the service-level in WCF using attributes

Comment: To the second bullet point: there is an api for accessing the config file. See the code in my answer for one way to do it. You do not have to resort to reading it as an xml file.