# What is TransactionScope default Timeout value?

Tags: c#, sql, transactionscope

When i create a TransactionScope object as followed:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
  // Do stuff...
}
```

What is the default transaction timeout of the given ts object?

Comment: From [this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/06/transactionscope-has-default-timeout.html) it appears that it is set to 1 minute.

Comment: Great [SO Post on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348191/default-transaction-timeout)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to David Browne it is 1 minute

> TransactionScope’s default constructor defaults the isolation level to Serializable and the timeout to 1 minute

[using new TransactionScope() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/archive/blogs/dbrowne/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 2):

> You can find the value like this.

var defaultTimeout= TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout;