# LinqToSQL ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I know this question has been asked many times however none of the answers fit my issue.
I have a thread timer firing every 30 seconds that queries a MSSQL db that is under heavy load. If i need to update the data in the console app that i'm using i use Linq To Sql to update the data stored in memory.

My problem is sometimes I get the error ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection.

The code from the thread timer fires a `Thread.Run(reload());`
The connection string is

```
//example code
void reload(...
    string connstring = string.Format("Data Source={0},{1};Initial Catalog={2};User ID={3};Password={4};Application Name={5};Connect Timeout=120;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=1524;Pooling=true;"
 settings = new ConnectionStringSettings("sqlServer", connstring, "System.Data.SqlClient");

  using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                  new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
                {

                    using (SwitchDataDataContext data = new SwitchDataDataContext(settings.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        data.CommandTimeout = 560;
```

then i do many linqtosql searches. The exceptions happen from time to time but not always on the same query's. it's like the connections is opened and is forced closed.
Sometimes the exceptions says the current status is Open, Closed, Connecting. I add a larger ThreadPool to the SQL db but nothing seems to help.

i also have ADO in other parts of the program without any issues.

Comment: 1. *MSSQL db under heavy load* 2. *every 30 seconds* 3. *data.CommandTimeout = 560* 4. *then i do many linqtosql searches*. That doesn't compute. I think you should at least look at some caching patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Linq To Sql to Entity Framework and received the same type of message. I believe the issues is lazy Loading. I was using the collections before it was ready on a different thread.  I just added   .Include("Lab") to my collection to load the entire collection and it seems to of fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that the transaction scope also has a timeout. The default timeout is 1 minute according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224748/what-is-transactionscope-default-timeout-value). So the transaction times out long before your command does (560 seconds = 9.3 minutes or so) . You will need to set the timeout property in the instance of the TransactionOptions object you are creating

```
new TransactionOptions()
{ 
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, 
    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,10,0) /* 10 Minutes */ 
}
```

You can verify that is indeed the issue by setting the TransactionScope timeout to a small value to force it to timeout.

Comment: same issue i guess i need to use ado :(

Comment: @AndreDeMattia note: a transaction that lasts that long is rarely a good idea