# what is the alternative approach for TransactionScope in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, transactionscope

I have used `TransactionScope` in `Controller` (C# web Api), while inserting records for huge data it throws an error. Exception is `Operation is not valid (TimeOut)`. But i don't feel so it is timeout error as data is not that much huge still records not getting inserted, Please provide any alternative for `TransactionScope`.

Thanks in advance...

Sample ref Code :

```
enter code here
try
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
       AddData(InputData); // method call business login and data access 
                            method
       scope.Complete();

    }
 }
catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
  {
     LogError(ex);

  }
```

Comment: It might be a deadlock issue due to mutli-threading...

Comment: So what is the solution for this..

Comment: I think you should show the relevant code here.

Comment: Why do you "feel" it is not a timeout issue? How much time does it take before giving you this error?

Comment: after 2 mins it throws error

Comment: And what is your timeout set to? (The default is 30 seconds)

Comment: Are you using SQL server?

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman - plz check code in abv desc

Comment: Mihail Stancescu  - yes

Comment: Colin Mackay - by default timeout is 10 min . I have no set anything

Comment: Try to change tx isolation level, like this: `scope = new TransactionOptions{IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted}`;

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server, the ADO.NET timeouts are 30 seconds unless set otherwise. Where do you get 10 minutes from? Also, please show the relevant code. There is code in `AddData()` that is likely relevant. If you are calling a stored procedure, that is likely relevant too.

Comment: Simon Mourier - OK Simon i will check this "isolation level"

Comment: `TransacationScope` default timeout — depends on how you instantiate the instance — is either 1 minute OR whatever value is used in `system.transactions/defaultTimeout` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348191/default-transaction-timeout). ADO.NET/ `SqlCommand` default timeout is 30 seconds.